# Using camera in auto with TTL master flash and non-TTL slaves

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-flash, ttl

What I'd like to be able to do is use one TTL master flash, perhaps connected directly to the camera with the camera in Av/Tv mode, and use a slave flash (or more than one) as either optical or wireless slaves. What I'd like to be able to do is get the non-TTL flashes to trigger while the camera is getting its TTL reading, as well as triggering again when the shutter is open for capturing the image. Is this possible?

I've read [this question and accepted answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53300/do-ttl-flashes-always-count-as-a-single-pre-flash/53301#53301) on mixing flash usage modes, but I'm not sure it really answers my question.

I understand that I can set the Non-TTL flashes to ignore a preflash (I'm using Yongnuo YN-560 flashes), but can I get them to fire for both a master preflash and a master flash? I have wireless triggers available (non-TTL) which I can use if these would help.

Comment: I'm afraid that in most cases the external flashlights will fire after the TTL flash has finished. Probably the proportion between internal flash duration and the delay until the external flashes fire is too bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the reason you're not able to fire on both the preflash and the main flash is that the time between them is too short and the slaves have not had enough time to recharge sufficiently. Try lowering the flash output on the slaves, or increasing the time between the preflash and main flash by half pressing the shutter (assuming your camera triggers the preflash while calculating the exposure at focus time.)